# For a Vector Space $V = A \oplus B = A \oplus C \implies \dim(B) = \dim(C) $?

Tags: vector-spaces

For a finite dimensional space there is no problem.
$\dim(V) = \dim(A) + \dim(B) = \dim(A) + \dim(C) \implies \dim(B) = \dim(C)$.

For an infinite dimensional space it  still holds that
$\dim(V) = \dim(A) + \dim(B) = \dim(A) + \dim(C)$.

But this can be satisfied for example by $\dim(V) = \aleph_0$; $\dim(A) = \aleph_0$; $\dim(B) = 1$; $\dim(C) = 2$.

Intuitively, I think the assertion is true. Can anyone give a proof (or counterexample) ?

(Note: $\oplus$ is the *direct sum*, so $A \cap B = A \cap C = \{0\}$ and $\operatorname{span}(A \cup B) = \operatorname{span} (A \cup C) = V$).

A further thought inspired by a now-deleted comment is to construct $V$ and $W$ as external direct sums from $A = \mathbb R^{\aleph_0}$; $B = \mathbb R$; $C = \mathbb R^2$ with $V = A \oplus B$ and $W = A \oplus C$. Then $\dim(V) = \dim(W) = \aleph_0$ so $V$ and $W$ are isomorphic, but are they equal (i.e. $x \in V \implies x \in W$ and vice versa) ?

---

The original context of the question was that if $f$ is a non-zero linear functional on a vector space $V$ one can establish that $V = \ker(f) \oplus \operatorname{span} (w)$ where $w$ is any vector outside the kernel. So I wanted to conclude that if $V = \ker(f) \oplus X$ then $\dim(X)= 1$. This would follow if the assertion here is true since $\dim(\operatorname{span}(w)) = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depends on the interpretation of $A \oplus B = V = A \oplus C$.

If this means, that $A,B,C$ are supspaces of a given vector space $V$ (Thus interpreting the direct sum as an internal direct sum), we get $B \cong V/A \cong C$, hence the assertion is true.

If we let the direct sum to be external and only assume $A \oplus B \cong A \oplus C$, the statement is of course false, since $K^{(\mathbb N)} \oplus K \cong K^{(\mathbb N)} \cong K^{(\mathbb N)} \oplus K^2$.

Comment: Writing $V=A\oplus B=A\oplus C$ strongly suggests the “internal” interpretation. Good answer anyway.

Comment: @egreg Yes, I originally had the internal direct sum in mind. By the way, what notation would suggest the external direct sum ?

Comment: @TomCollinge Unfortunately the usage is ambiguous; but here the equals signs are the clue.

Comment: Thanks for the answer: I'll have to revise my notes on quotient spaces and direct sums in order to fully appreciate it. Suppose though that we have $A \oplus B = A \oplus C$ in the sense that $R^3$ is the external direct sum of a given plane and any non co-planar line.  What does that say about the dimension of $B, C$  in the infinite case ?

Answer (score 0):

Every vector space has a basis: so if you pick a basis for $A$ and a basis for $B$, then you obtain a basis $\{a_i\}_{i \in I} \cup \{b_j\}_{j \in J}$ for $V$.

We can express each $b_j$ as $a'_j + c_j$ for some unique $a'_j \in A$, $c_j \in C$. Then we get a new basis for $V = A \oplus C$ given by $\{a_i\}_{i \in I} \cup \{c_j\}_{j \in J}$. The $c_j$ form a basis for $C$, so $\dim C = \text{card } J = \dim B$.

Comment: I'm trying to convince myself that $\{a_i\}_{i \in I} \cup \{c_j\}_{j \in J}$ is a linearly independent set and that $ \{c_j\}_{j \in J}$ is a basis for $C$.

Comment: This follows because we can write each $a'_j$ as a unique linear combination of the $\{a_i\}$ - if you had a linear relation amongst the $a_i$s and $c_j$s then you'd get one among the $a_i$s and $b_j$s.

The $c_j$ span $C$ because the $a_i$ and $c_j$ span $V$, and the $a_i$ form a basis for $A$ - so anything in $C$ can be written as a linear combination of the $a_i$ and $c_j$, and you then can see you didn't use any of the $a_i$ in the linear combination. (If you want me to be more precise / write up a full proof I can do so, but that should be enough to reconstruct it.)